# C++ Type casting base object to derived object

Tags: c++

So I have a dynamically allocated array of base class. I've stored a few objects of its derived class inside the array.

The student (base) class and its derived classes all have a `getInfo()` function, obviously the derived classes have overrided that base `getInfo()`. The goal is to used the `getinfo` function from the base class, then type class the two objects of the derived class, back into the derived class and use the overrided `getinfo()`.

Everything up to "break" works perfect. It's figuring out how to type cast the objects back into the derived classes that's killing me.

I've identified a few possible issues:

1) I didnt dynamically allocate correctly. Very possible because I hate pointers and very much suck at them.

2) I have no idea what Im doing with regard to actually type casting.

A few things of note:

1) The base class getinfo is not virtual

2) I am not allowed to modify the base class.

So, saviors of confusing code. What say you? Can you help this poor student out?

EDIT!!!

Updated code, now getting "Static_cast from Student ** to Gradstudent * is not allowed"

```
#include <iostream>

#include "GradStudent.h"
#include "UndergradStudent.h"

int main()
{
    int arraySize = 3;
    Student* classRoom[arraySize];

    GradStudent gst1("Ta", "Da", 4444, 'A', "Death");
    cout << gst1;

    UndergradStudent ust1("Bluh", "Bluh", 2222, 1);
    cout << ust1;

    Student bst1( "Blah", "Blah", 1111 );

    classRoom[0] = &bst1;
    classRoom[1] = &gst1;
    classRoom[2] = &ust1;



    for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++)
    {
        cout << classRoom[x]->getInfo();
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "TEST" << endl;

    GradStudent* gStudent =  static_cast<GradStudent*>(&classRoom[2]);
    cout << gStudent->getInfo();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "So i have a dynamically allocated array of base class." **No**. You have an array of **pointers to** objects of a base class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` returns the casted pointer, it does not modify the parameter itself.

You need to do something like below.

```
// removed the & since the elements are now pointers
GradStudent* gStudent =  dynamic_cast<GradStudent*>(classRoom[1]); 
cout << gStudent->getInfo();
```

Caveat - for pointers, if it fails to cast `dynamic_cast` will return `nullptr`, you need to check for this to prevent a crash.

EDIT: Major [Object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) bug in your code - #1 is almost right

```
int arraySize = 3;
Student *classRoom;
classRoom = new Student[arraySize];

GradStudent gst1("Ta", "Da", 4444, 'A', "Death");
...
classRoom[0] = gst1;
```

Should be

```
int arraySize = 3;
Student **classRoom;
//      ^
classRoom = new Student*[arraySize];
//                     ^
GradStudent gst1("Ta", "Da", 4444, 'A', "Death");

classRoom[0] = &gst1;
//             ^
```

Or just

```
Student* classRoom[3];

GradStudent gst1("Ta", "Da", 4444, 'A', "Death");
...
classRoom[0] = gst1;
```

Without this, all data belonging to the derived class is lost, and the base class data alone is stored, this is called **Object Slicing**.

Comment: Oops, Im actually using static_cast right now. Also not working (I was just throwing random casts at it out of annoyance)

Comment: @user2036101 same behaviour, the return value is the casted pointer

Comment: Ok, so its working now, except when I print out the type casted object, I get a bizarre error thats more of a mixture of both derived objects.

Comment: @user2036101 please see my edit, you have an object slicing problem.

Comment: Ok, any idea where I could read up on Object Slicing for future reference? 

Also what does the ** signify?

Comment: @user2036101 pls see my edit for wikipedia link. You need to store array of pointers, so ** is a pointer to a (in this case) dynamically allocated array of pointers.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code but I have a new error "Static_cast from Student ** to Gradstudent * is not allowed"

Comment: @user2036101 let me fix my orig answer, you dont need the & any more.

Answer (score 0):

For polymorphism to work you need to use pointers to objects.  When you do

```
classRoom[1] = gst1;
```

C++ is storing the Student part of the GradStudent object in classRoom[1].

Comment: So what exactly am I doing wrong? Im very weak with pointers overall.

Comment: @Karthik explained it well.