# Access child class' functions within parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've been coding a simple board game to learn concepts of C++ in practice. I have implemented the board: it consists of tiles, each of which is a child class inheriting from a parent class. The board is a class that has a vector of the tiles.

There are several kinds of tiles. Some of them can be bought by players. There are several different kinds of buyable tiles as well with different properties, so I deemed it cute to make a base class TileOnSale for tiles that can be bought and make child classes of the actual types, two of which I have provided in the below code.

Now my problem is that how can I access the child members' functions not defined within the parent class (TileOnSale)? Board gets initialized with all kinds of different tiles, so I can extract a Tile from there using getTile(int location) function. However, this gets interpreted as just a Tile, not a TileOnSale or a StreetTile. I know of no way to grasp StreetTile's buildHouses function this way.

So, is there a robust, or even better, a neat way of doing this? Can I make a template or something to hold Tile objects that might be StreetTiles or StationTiles or something else that is a Tile?
Or should I just redesign the class structure?

Here's a bare bones code. I have tried to provide only what is needed for understanding the question. Also, originally Tile and Board were in their own header files. I decided it not necessary to show the Player class that has a vector of owned TileOnSale objects but which retains the exact same access problem as Board.

```
// Board.h
#include "Tile.h"
typedef vector<Tile> Tiles;

class Board
{
public:
    Board();
    ~Board();
    Tile            getTile(int location);
private:
    Tiles           tiles;
};

// Tile.h
class Tile
{
public:
    Tile();
    ~Tile();
protected:
    tileType    tile_type; // this is enum containing unique type
    string      description;
};

class TileOnSale : public Tile
{
public:
    TileOnSale();
    ~TileOnSale();

    virtual int getRent() const { return 0; };
};

class StreetTile : public TileOnSale 
{
public:
    StreetTile();
    ~StreetTile();
    int getRent() override;
    void buildHouses(int number);
private:
    int houses;
};

class StationTile : public TileOnSale
{
public:
    StationTile();
    ~StationTile();
    int getRent() override;
};
```

EDIT: added a potentially clarifying comment to code.

Comment: Not sure this is what you want. But have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948957/c-type-casting-base-object-to-derived-object

Comment: Yes; that looks like what I intend. Thanks, I see there are several ways of doing this.

Comment: Same remark by the way: you should use a vector<Tile*>.

Comment: The first comment (by VusP) was very useful information for me. While visitor pattern has solved several problems, pointer casting has solved a couple of others. So, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

> In essence, the visitor allows one to add new virtual functions to a family of classes without modifying the classes themselves; instead, one creates a visitor class that implements all of the appropriate specializations of the virtual function. The visitor takes the instance reference as input, and implements the goal through double dispatch.

The double dispatch means  you are actually calling a virtual function twice: first on the subject which in turn polymorphically calls the visitor.

In your case there is just one method, namely building houses, but you might want to add others later (like drawing them on a screen for example). Given your current example you should add this method to Tile and StreetTile:

```
virtual void accept(Visitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
```

This is the Visitor base class implementation:

```
class Visitor {
public:
    virtual void accept(Tile& t) = 0;
    virtual void accept(StreetTile& t) = 0;
};
```

After that you can implement a Builder class:

```
class Builder: public Visitor {
private:
    int numberOfHouses;
public:
    Builder(int n): numberOfHouses(n) {}
    virtual void accept(Tile& t) {}
    virtual void accept(StreetTile& t) {
        t.buildHouses(numberOfHouses);
    }
};
```

After that all you have to do is construct such a builder, and call it on every tile in your vector of tiles:

```
Builder b(10);
for (Tile tile : tiles) {
    tile.accept(b);
}
```

Comment: Woah, I didn't know about this but it looks cool. I indeed want to add more methods (sellHouses etc.), having shown only one because buildHouses was sufficient to explain the idea. I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: Not yet, because I haven't had time to look at it further. However, I think I'll first try this approach because it looks so nice.

Comment: I read a little more about the visitor pattern and while I haven't implemented it yet, it is most definitely the neatest way presented here to accomplish what I want. Also, it quite nicely solves another problem, a player arriving in a certain tile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Simple way is to add a unique id (enum or string) to each type. The player class can ask for the type (defined in the base class) and cast to the derived class accordingly.

Since it needs to call a function on the derived (e.g. specialized) class it has the knowledge to perform the cast.

Having a type ID is also nice for debugging purposes.

Comment: I suppose if I implemented a function for each return type that might actually work, given I have less than ten different kinds of children to Tile. It wouldn't be that neat though, code in them would be almost identical. =) Also, I already have a type to each Tile (enum tileType) though I seem to have forgotten to include its definition.